# Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.5 navbar drop-down pull-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make the drop-down go to the extreme right, after the search input and submit button, tried pull-right, navbar-right but to no avail.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>              
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

[image]

I'm trying this:
[image]

Comment: I tested a few things, and couldn't get it to work.  Maybe someone else can use this to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/vk2c5gar/

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure, but what it does if you change the login part ul from:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
```

to:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right pull-right">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the links after the search form :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>              
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

And this is the CSS for it :

```
#navbar{
    float:right !important;
}
.navbar-form{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/fkhg9jaw/)

Note : For the mobile version , you only need to make this under the right media query :

```
#navbar{
    float:none !important;
}
```